# How to Grep Search two occurrences of a character in a lookbetween

Tags: regex, grep, html-parsing, textwrangler, bbedit

I seem to have to perpetually relearn Regex & Grep syntax every time I need something advanced. This time, even with BBEDIT's pattern playground, I can't work this one out.

I need to do a multi-line search for the occurrence of two literal asterisks anywhere in the text between a pair of   tags in a plist/XML file.

I can successfully construct a lookbetween so:

```
(?s)(?<=<array>).*?(?=</array>)
```

I try to limit that to only match occurrences in which two asterisks appear between tags:

```
(?s)(?<=<array>).*?[*]{2}.*?(?=</array>)
(?s)(?<=<array>).+[*]{2}.+(?=</array>)
(?s)(?<=<array>).+?[*]{2}.+?(?=</array>)
```

But they find nought. And when I remove the {2} I realize I'm not even constructing it right to find occurrences of one asterisk. I tried escaping the character /* and [/*] but to no avail.

How can i match any occurrence of  blah blah * blah blah * blah blah ?

Comment: `.` matches any char, you are not limiting anything when using `.*` or `.+` in the patterns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[*]{2}` means the two asterisks must be consecutive.

`(.*[*]){2}` is what you're looking for - it contains two asterisks, with anything in between them.

But we also need to make sure the regex is only testing one tag closure at the same time, so instead of `.*`, we need to use `((?!<\/array>).)*` to make sure it won't consume the end tag `</array>` while matching `.*`

The regex can be written as:

```
(?s)(?<=<array>)(?:((?!<\/array>).)*?[*]){2}(?1)*
```

See the test result [here](https://regex101.com/r/2VaHtW/1)

Answer (score 1):

Use

```js
(?s)(?<=<array>)(?:(?:(?!<\/?array>)[^*])*[*]){2}.*?(?=</array>)
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/WmXSrW/2).

**Explanation**

| NODE | EXPLANATION |
| --- | --- |
| `(?s)` | set flags for this block (with . matching \n) (case-sensitive) (with ^ and $ matching normally) (matching whitespace and # normally) |
| `(?<=` | look behind to see if there is: |
| `<array>` | `'<array>'` |
| `)` | end of look-behind |
| `(?:` | group, but do not capture (2 times): |
| `(?:` | group, but do not capture (0 or more times (matching the most amount possible)): |
| `(?!` | look ahead to see if there is not: |
| `</?array>` | `</array>` or `<array>` |
| `)` | end of look-ahead |
| `[^*]` | any character except: '*' |
| `)*` | end of grouping |
| `[*]` | any character of: '*' |
| `){2}` | end of grouping |
| `.*?` | any character (0 or more times (matching the least amount possible)) |
| `(?=` | look ahead to see if there is: |
| `</array>` | `'</array>'` |
| `)` | end of look-ahead |

Comment: This is a slightly less compact expression than Hao Wu's answer, which I had already accepted, but it too works and I truly appreciate the effort you put in to break down the logic element by element. If I am reading this right, it's slightly more efficient than Hao Wu's in that it groups and eliminates any tag pair with NO askerisk in it [^*] before testing for two occurrences. Did I get that right?

Comment: @brianfit This solution is more precise as it does not overlap array tags not having double asterisks. Only the tags with double asterisks will get matched thanks to a tempered greedy token. It is not that fast, but makes matching more precise. Cf. [Wu's](https://regex101.com/r/i4Muic/1) and [mine](https://regex101.com/r/i4Muic/2)